# Ionic Angular How to run application with get parameter

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have an Angular app based on Ionic 5 with capacitor.

I need to run my app with specific parameter. Example:

```
https://localhost/start-url?someparam=xxx
```

So I will be redirected to 'start-url' from router **redirectTo**. But how to add the Get param also?

Thank you

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-query-parameters

Answer (score 0):

Firslty call your API with a post method.

```js
callApi(params): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient
      .post<any>(`localhost....ect`, params)
}
```

Second call your service from .ts. Inject the service into constructor and pass your params.

If you want to pass data from page to page use routerLink and [state]

```js
  routerLink="/app/tabs/...ect"
                [state]="{params : someData}"
```

Comment: Thank you. But I;m looking for a way without double-redirecting. I want just load the app with the url with get param.